# Is there any drupal module to export/import all ubercart products with product details(attributes)

Tags: 7, ubercart

I am looking for the module which having the option to import all ubercart products including all information like product images, price, sale price and other attributes. After exporting the information how we can import these to other drupal setup.

If there is no single module to do this then what will be the right approach to do the same.

Answer (score 1):

I would use start by having a look at [UberCart Feeds](https://www.drupal.org/project/uc_feeds) with  [uc_feeds_product_importer](https://www.drupal.org/node/1802908)  they should help you get the job done.